# Get "Unable to extract symbolic link" error message when trying to install civicrm 5.19.1 module in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I installed Drupal 7 and when I try to add the civicrm (version 5.19.1) module into it, I get next error message on the web interface of Drupal:

> Unable to extract symbolic link
>   {temporary://update-extraction-0a20b282/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/README.rst}

and the module is not installed. I would like to know how to solve this.

Comment: The tar.gz archive contains a broken symbolic link: `civicrm/vendor/pear/README.rst` pointing to an unexisting `docs/guide.txt` file.

Comment: Are you following the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/drupal7/ ?

Comment: Yes. Where I have the alternative, I choose: "As administrator in Drupal, go to Modules, click on Install New Module , and it will ask you to fill in the URL of the module. It will then fetch it and install it for you".

Comment: I'm getting the same error in 5.19.3 upgrade install: `tar: civicrm/vendor/pear/log/README.rst: Cannot create symlink to 'docs/guide.txt': No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors` Is there a work around?

Comment: Yes, the workaround is to upgrade from the command line interface and to extract the files from the `tar.gz` achive. If you don't have access to the hosting system with the shell, extract the `tar.gz` archive on your own desktop/laptop, remove the offending `civicrm/vendor/pear/log/README.rst` symbolic link and copy the remaining extracted files to the remote directory.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: This is now fixed in 5.31.

---

I see what you're saying. Thanks for reporting. I've never used that alternative before. I believe it's coming from this line where it excludes the docs folder so the symlink is no longer valid.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.19.1/distmaker/dists/common.sh#L166

I've made a ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1393

Comment: So, it is a bug.

Comment: Is there an update on this problem? I am trying to install CiviCRM 5.23.0 on Drupal 8.8.3 and I get the same error message

Comment: You can't install civi on drupal 8 from that screen anyway. Drupal 8 requires using composer.

Comment: sorry and thanks!

Comment: @gebseng - re progress: you can check by following the link above to the issue ticket.  So far, no progress has been recorded.

Comment: Will be fixed in 5.31.